# What is the order in which the hooks (plugins) of Chart.js are executed?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The documentation of chartJS plugins is available [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html), however it is incomplete as there is no full description of each of the hooks:

- `afterInit`
- `beforeUpdate (cancellable)`
- `afterUpdate`
- `beforeLayout (cancellable)`
- `afterLayout`
- `beforeDatasetsUpdate (cancellable)`
- `afterDatasetsUpdate`
- `beforeDatasetUpdate (cancellable)`
- `afterDatasetUpdate`
- `beforeRender (cancellable)`
- `afterRender`
- `beforeDraw (cancellable)`
- `afterDraw`
- `beforeDatasetsDraw (cancellable)`
- `afterDatasetsDraw`
- `beforeDatasetDraw (cancellable)`
- `afterDatasetDraw`
- `beforeEvent (cancellable)`
- `afterEvent`
- `resize`
- `destroy`

This list can be summarize to the following functions, yet the order is not clear for me:

- Update
- Layout
- DatasetsUpdate
- DatasetUpdate
- Render
- Draw
- DatasetsDraw
- DatasetDraw
- Event
- resize
- destroy

Some of the names might know what is the order of execution of the hooks.

---

#### Use case

I want to implement several behaviours on the charts that activate on certain conditions on the data, as an example, I want to update the legend labels when there is no data available, so, instead of displaying the name of the *category* in the legend, it would display a message saying *no data*.

To be sure, ***I have manage to implement plugins***, but since the order is not clear for me, I keep getting things mixed up due to the order.

Comment: Not quite the order, but I found the internal documentation of each of the hooks in [the code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/30cb91d2eb307718965d24efd46444a9ed8a3209/src/core/core.plugins.js#L174). Still the order is not clear.

Answer (score 15):

I found the internal documentation of each of the hooks in [the code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/30cb91d2eb307718965d24efd46444a9ed8a3209/src/core/core.plugins.js#L174) (see Below for a prettified version). **Not quite the order, but it can help figuring it out**.

Note that some hooks have the same name but they differ in the parameters (you can check those directly in [the code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/30cb91d2eb307718965d24efd46444a9ed8a3209/src/core/core.plugins.js#L174):

- `beforeInit`: Called before initializing `chart`.
- `afterInit`: Called after `chart` has been initialized and before the first update.
- `beforeUpdate`: Called before updating `chart`. If any plugin returns `false`, the update is cancelled (and thus subsequent render(s)) until another `update` is triggered.
- `afterUpdate`: Called after `chart` has been updated and before rendering. Note that this hook will not be called if the chart update has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeDatasetsUpdate`: Called before updating the `chart` datasets. If any plugin returns `false`, the datasets update is cancelled until another `update` is triggered. @since version 2.1.5
- `afterDatasetsUpdate`: Called after the `chart` datasets have been updated. Note that this hook will not be called if the datasets update has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeDatasetUpdate`: Called before updating the `chart` dataset at the given `args.index`. If any plugin returns `false`, the datasets update is cancelled until another `update` is triggered.
- `afterDatasetUpdate`: Called after the `chart` datasets at the given `args.index` has been updated. Note that this hook will not be called if the datasets update has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeLayout`: Called before laying out `chart`. If any plugin returns `false`, the layout update is cancelled until another `update` is triggered.
- `afterLayout`: Called after the `chart` has been layed out. Note that this hook will not be called if the layout update has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeRender`: Called before rendering `chart`. If any plugin returns `false`, the rendering is cancelled until another `render` is triggered.
- `afterRender`: Called after the `chart` has been fully rendered (and animation completed). Note that this hook will not be called if the rendering has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeDraw`: Called before drawing `chart` at every animation frame specified by the given easing value. If any plugin returns `false`, the frame drawing is cancelled until another `render` is triggered.
- `afterDraw`: Called after the `chart` has been drawn for the specific easing value. Note that this hook will not be called if the drawing has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeDatasetsDraw`: Called before drawing the `chart` datasets. If any plugin returns `false`, the datasets drawing is cancelled until another `render` is triggered.
- `afterDatasetsDraw`: Called after the `chart` datasets have been drawn. Note that this hook will not be called if the datasets drawing has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeDatasetDraw`: Called before drawing the `chart` dataset at the given `args.index` (datasets are drawn in the reverse order). If any plugin returns `false`, the datasets drawing is cancelled until another `render` is triggered.
- `afterDatasetDraw`: Called after the `chart` datasets at the given `args.index` have been drawn (datasets are drawn in the reverse order). Note that this hook will not be called if the datasets drawing has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeTooltipDraw`: Called before drawing the `tooltip`. If any plugin returns `false`, the tooltip drawing is cancelled until another `render` is triggered.
- `afterTooltipDraw`: Called after drawing the `tooltip`. Note that this hook will not be called if the tooltip drawing has been previously cancelled.
- `beforeEvent`: Called before processing the specified `event`. If any plugin returns `false`, the event will be discarded.
- `afterEvent`: Called after the `event` has been consumed. Note that this hook will not be called if the `event` has been previously discarded.
- `resize`: Called after the chart as been resized.
- `destroy`: Called after the chart as been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

old question but in chart.js 4.4.0, you can get a sense of order by stepping through Chart class (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.controller.js) which works out to:

1. beforeUpdate
2. BeforeElementsUpdate
3. beforeLayout
4. afterLayout
5. reset(if animations disabled)
6. beforeDatasetsUpdate
7. beforeDatasetUpdate
8. afterDatasetUpdate
9. afterDatasetsUpdate
10. afterUpdate
11. beforeRender
12. beforeDraw
13. beforeDatasetsDraw
14. beforeDatasetDraw
15. afterDatasetDraw
16. afterDatasetsDraw
17. afterDraw
18. afterRender

before/afterInit and before/afterEvent hooks will happen before the above and before/afterDestroy happens on its own.